# Avoid passing parameter from high to low-level classes

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles

In my Java web server project, my `Main.main` method takes an argument specifying the directory where it will look for certain files, that I use later on. My issue is that I don't actually do anything with that argument in my higher-level classes, but the information is needed by some of my lower-level ones.

Naturally, the class that parses and stores my command line arguments is one of the first ones that is used, i.e. one of my highest level classes, so I'm struggling to find a way to make the command line argument accessible to my low-level classes.

It seems like my only two options are to either pass it all the way down, through classes that never touch the argument other than to pass it to the next level, or to give it a global scope. Neither of these seem like great options from a design perspective, so I'm wondering if there's an alternative that I'm missing, or if I just have to pick the lesser of two evils-- or totally revamp the way my classes are structured.

Comment: Your instincts are correct, neither passing it around or global state are great options, but then you accepted an answer that only suggested those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are many options to do that:

1. As you said pass it all the way down - possible, but quite not good, because absolutely all methods in all call path must have it as parameter.
2. Use system property instead of `main` method parameter and

   a. call your main as `>java -Dmy.path=path_to_directory` Main

   b. use environment variable

   `>set my.path=path_to_directory`
   `>java Main`

   c. set it in the `main` method:

   `public void main(String[] args) {`
       `System.getProperties().put("my.path",args[dirPathIndex]);`

   In all cases you can get a value anywhere in the code just as:

   `String dirPath=System.getProperty("my.path");`
3. Create a small local static "kind of cache"
   in Main class

   `public class Main{`

   `public static String dirPath;`

   `public void main(String[] args) {`
      `dirPath= args[dirPathIndex];`

Then also, anywhere in the code you can get it as:

```
   `String dPath=Main.dirPath;`
```

Of course there are more options around "local cache" approach, but main idea still the same. Keep a value somewhere, you can get it at any place in the code.

Comment: All of your solutions from b onward are the same; global data. There is nothing SOLID about global data.

Comment: @weston Nothing wrong with that as long as it is a GLOBAL parameter. But there are tons of other approaches like introducing PropertyProvider, Context, injection, using inheritance or interface and so and so... All depends on exact need for each particular case.

Comment: I wasn't shouting by the way, SOLID is an acronym. OP said: "*It seems like my only two options are to either pass it all the way down, through classes that never touch the argument other than to pass it to the next level, or to give it a global scope. Neither of these seem like great options from a design perspective*" You only gave them back those two same options.

Comment: That's correct, but it is a reasonable solution for that case. From other hands if requirement tells that different instances of downstream objects may have different values of `path` - that is another case and needs to have different solution.

Comment: Reading of global data makes for hard to test and hard to scale code.

Comment: @weston IMHO not at all, but passing parameter through the stack is really hard. What about `Context` conception using everywhere in almost all frameworks and API?

Comment: I agree that is hard too. Which is why it's better to pass dependencies into constructors rather than create (`new`) them in a method. When one create's them inside a class is when that class gains all of the dependencies that the thing it's creating has. That is what Roberts answer is demonstrating.

Comment: Anyway if something is a global parameter it is better to work with it as global parameter, rather than build more complexity just to avoid usage that thing in its nature. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are right to avoid passing down some arguments through classes that don't need them. The trick with this is that the low-level objects, when designed properly, are still constructed at high level, which means you normally pass the needed arguments right there somewhere at the top of your application.

An example with two levels. Instead of doing this:

```java
public class ObjectA {
    public ObjectA(String path) {
        ....
        b = new ObjectB(path);
    }
}

public class ObjectB {
    public ObjectB(String path) {
        ...
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    new ObjectA(path);
}
```

where you pass `path` to `ObjectA` just because it needs to construct `ObjectB` with that argument, you do this:

```java
public class ObjectA {
    public ObjectA(ObjectB b) {
        ....
    }
}

public class ObjectB {
    public ObjectB(String path) {
        ...
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    new ObjectA(new ObjectB(path));
}
```

This is avoiding *propagating dependencies*, and is usually part of *dependency injection*. DI has a mixed reputation because it was co-opted by containers like Spring and JEE, but at its core DI actually only means that you shouldn't instantiate objects (even the lower level ones) in other objects, rather, already configured objects should be passed into other objects. This effectively decouples object construction and configuration from the objects that use it.

This might sound weird at first to construct an application this way, and it has all sorts of curious consequences for the design, but it is the right (OO) way to do things and it solves your problem.

Comment: But what to do if ObjectB creates not by ObjectA, but by ObjectC which has no idea about `path`? Only make ObjectC with constructor `path` parameter too... so there is no much difference from passing `path` as parameter of the method. It has the same requirement - all objects down the calling route must have defined place of `path`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. The difference between passing `path` or some object is that `ObjectC` does *not* need the path, but it *does* need `ObjectB` (or whatever). So you are passing something that is *should* know about.

Comment: Also, dependencies don't compound this way. `ObjectC` need `ObjectB` to work, but does not need anything that `ObjectB` needs. So it only know about things that it needs *directly*.

Comment: It is a simple question. In ObjectC you need to create ObjectB which has a `path` as constructor parameter - from where can you get it in ObjectC ? That's what I tried to ask... BTW there is nothing wrong with any of those approaches.

Comment: The point is, normally you don't *really* need to create `ObjectB` in `ObjectC`. You just want an instance of `ObjectB` because it has some functionality you want. Even if you *do* need to create a new instance, you can pass a *Factory* that is able to create an `ObjectB` without knowing what is needed for its creation. This is the OO way to avoid the original problem posted.

Comment: I agree, Factory is a way as well. But Factory must know about `path` parameter required to create ObjectB... so it goes to the same question from where Factory will take it?

Comment: Yes, the Factory knows about `path`, but the Factory does not need to be created inside `ObjectC`. The Factory is created at the top (in the main() for example, where the other object are created), and passed into `ObjectC`.

Comment: Sure. As I said there are tons of possible approaches based on the each particular use cases.